# Вычислить количество товаров в каждой подпапке

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

Имеется CSV со строками URL вида:

```
/cat1-name/sub-cat-1/item-1.html
/cat1-name/sub-cat-1/item-2.html
/cat1-name/sub-cat-1/item-3.html
/cat1-name/sub-cat-1/item-4.html
/cat1-name/sub-cat-1/item-5.html
/cat1-name/sub-cat-1/item-6.html
/cat1-name/sub-cat-1/item-7.html
/cat1-name/sub-cat-1/item-8.html
/cat1-name/sub-cat-1/item-9.html
/cat1-name/sub-cat-1/item-10.html
/cat1-name/sub-cat-1/item-11.html
/cat1-name/sub-cat-1/item-12.html
/cat1-name/sub-cat-1/item-13.html
/cat1-name/sub-cat-1/item-14.html
/cat1-name/sub-cat-1/item-15.html
/cat1-name/sub-cat-1/item-16.html
/cat1-name/sub-cat-1/item-17.html
/cat1-name/sub-cat-1/item-18.html
/cat1-name/sub-cat-1/item-19.html
/cat1-name/sub-cat-1/item-20.html
/cat1-name/sub-cat-1/item-21.html
/cat1-name/sub-cat-1/item-22.html
/cat1-name/sub-cat-1/item-23.html
/cat1-name/sub-cat-1/item-24.html
/cat1-name/sub-cat-1/item-25.html
/cat1-name/sub-cat-2/item-1.html
/cat1-name/sub-cat-2/item-2.html
/cat1-name/sub-cat-2/item-3.html
/cat1-name/sub-cat-2/item-4.html
/cat1-name/sub-cat-2/item-5.html
/cat1-name/sub-cat-2/item-6.html
/cat1-name/sub-cat-2/item-7.html
/cat1-name/sub-cat-2/item-8.html
/cat1-name/sub-cat-2/item-9.html
/cat1-name/sub-cat-2/item-10.html
/cat1-name/sub-cat-2/item-11.html
/cat1-name/sub-cat-2/item-12.html
/cat1-name/sub-cat-3/item-1.html
/cat1-name/sub-cat-3/item-2.html
/cat1-name/sub-cat-3/item-3.html
/cat1-name/sub-cat-3/item-4.html
/cat1-name/sub-cat-3/item-5.html
/cat1-name/sub-cat-3/item-6.html
/cat1-name/sub-cat-3/item-7.html
/cat1-name/sub-cat-3/item-8.html
/cat1-name/sub-cat-3/item-9.html
/cat1-name/sub-cat-3/item-10.html
/cat1-name/sub-cat-3/item-11.html
/cat1-name/sub-cat-3/item-12.html
/cat1-name/sub-cat-3/item-13.html
/cat1-name/sub-cat-3/item-14.html
/cat1-name/sub-cat-3/item-15.html
/cat1-name/sub-cat-3/item-16.html
/cat1-name/sub-cat-3/item-17.html
/cat1-name/sub-cat-3/item-18.html
/cat1-name/sub-cat-3/item-19.html
/cat1-name/sub-cat-3/item-20.html
/cat1-name/sub-cat-3/item-21.html
/cat1-name/sub-cat-3/item-22.html
/cat1-name/sub-cat-4/item-1.html
/cat1-name/sub-cat-4/item-2.html
/cat1-name/sub-cat-4/item-3.html
/cat1-name/sub-cat-4/item-4.html
/cat1-name/sub-cat-4/item-5.html
/cat1-name/sub-cat-4/item-6.html
/cat1-name/sub-cat-4/item-7.html
/cat1-name/sub-cat-4/item-8.html
/cat1-name/sub-cat-4/item-9.html
/cat1-name/sub-cat-4/item-10.html
/cat1-name/sub-cat-4/item-11.html
/cat1-name/sub-cat-4/item-12.html
/cat1-name/sub-cat-4/item-13.html
/cat1-name/sub-cat-4/item-14.html
/cat1-name/sub-cat-4/item-15.html
/cat1-name/sub-cat-4/item-16.html
/cat1-name/image-1.html
/cat1-name/image-2.html
/cat2-name/item-1.html
/cat2-name/item-2.html
/cat2-name/item-3.html
/cat2-name/item-4.html
/cat2-name/item-5.html
/cat2-name/item-6.html
/cat2-name/item-7.html
/cat2-name/item-8.html
/cat2-name/item-9.html
/cat2-name/item-10.html
/cat2-name/item-11.html
/cat2-name/item-12.html
/cat2-name/item-13.html
/cat2-name/item-14.html
/cat2-name/item-15.html
/cat2-name/item-16.html
/cat2-name/image-1.html
/cat2-name/image-2.html
```

и т.д.
Строки отсортированы по имени категории, подкатегории и объекту

Мне нужно подсчитать:

общее количество item в категории;
количество item в каждой подкатегории;
количество image в каждой категории.

Задача тривиальная, но справиться пока не выходит.

Попытался начать с простого: для каждой категории создал объект класса, записал полный список URL, относящихся к категории, подсчитал общее количество item для каждой категории.

Далее попытался для каждой подкатегории подсчитать:

```
for cat in categoryList:
    persubcat = 0
    newSerList.clear()
    exstr = ""
    images = 0
    for i in range(cat.totalItems):
        if(exstr == ""):
            exstr = cat.url[i]
            persubcat += 1
        else:
            if(cat.url[i].split("/")[2] == exstr.split("/")[2]):
                persubcat += 1
            elif(cat.url[i].split("/")[2].split("/")[0] == "image"):
                images += 1
            elif(cat.url[i].split("/")[2].split("/")[0] == "item"):
                persubcat += 1
            elif(cat.url[i].split("/")[2] != exstr.split("/")[2]):
                persubcat += 1
                subcatLsit.append(persubcat)
        
    cat.subcats = subcatList
    subcatList.clear()
    persubcat = 0
```

Выглядит ужасно, работает тоже (не работает). Прошу неравнодушных помочь. Спасибо

Comment: есть только категория-подкатегория или предполагается еще более глубокое вложение?

Comment: @Zhihar только категория-подкатегория. Также некоторые лежат в корне категории

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Наверное, тут удобнее использовать `Pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd

s = '''/cat1-name/sub-cat-1/item-1.html
/cat1-name/sub-cat-1/item-2.html
/cat1-name/sub-cat-1/item-3.html
/cat1-name/sub-cat-1/item-4.html
/cat1-name/sub-cat-1/item-5.html
/cat1-name/sub-cat-1/item-6.html
/cat1-name/sub-cat-1/item-7.html
/cat1-name/sub-cat-1/item-8.html
/cat1-name/sub-cat-1/item-9.html
/cat1-name/sub-cat-1/item-10.html
/cat1-name/sub-cat-1/item-11.html
/cat1-name/sub-cat-1/item-12.html
/cat1-name/sub-cat-1/item-13.html
/cat1-name/sub-cat-1/item-14.html
/cat1-name/sub-cat-1/item-15.html
/cat1-name/sub-cat-1/item-16.html
/cat1-name/sub-cat-1/item-17.html
/cat1-name/sub-cat-1/item-18.html
/cat1-name/sub-cat-1/item-19.html
/cat1-name/sub-cat-1/item-20.html
/cat1-name/sub-cat-1/item-21.html
/cat1-name/sub-cat-1/item-22.html
/cat1-name/sub-cat-1/item-23.html
/cat1-name/sub-cat-1/item-24.html
/cat1-name/sub-cat-1/item-25.html
/cat1-name/sub-cat-2/item-1.html
/cat1-name/sub-cat-2/item-2.html
/cat1-name/sub-cat-2/item-3.html
/cat1-name/sub-cat-2/item-4.html
/cat1-name/sub-cat-2/item-5.html
/cat1-name/sub-cat-2/item-6.html
/cat1-name/sub-cat-2/item-7.html
/cat1-name/sub-cat-2/item-8.html
/cat1-name/sub-cat-2/item-9.html
/cat1-name/sub-cat-2/item-10.html
/cat1-name/sub-cat-2/item-11.html
/cat1-name/sub-cat-2/item-12.html
/cat1-name/sub-cat-3/item-1.html
/cat1-name/sub-cat-3/item-2.html
/cat1-name/sub-cat-3/item-3.html
/cat1-name/sub-cat-3/item-4.html
/cat1-name/sub-cat-3/item-5.html
/cat1-name/sub-cat-3/item-6.html
/cat1-name/sub-cat-3/item-7.html
/cat1-name/sub-cat-3/item-8.html
/cat1-name/sub-cat-3/item-9.html
/cat1-name/sub-cat-3/item-10.html
/cat1-name/sub-cat-3/item-11.html
/cat1-name/sub-cat-3/item-12.html
/cat1-name/sub-cat-3/item-13.html
/cat1-name/sub-cat-3/item-14.html
/cat1-name/sub-cat-3/item-15.html
/cat1-name/sub-cat-3/item-16.html
/cat1-name/sub-cat-3/item-17.html
/cat1-name/sub-cat-3/item-18.html
/cat1-name/sub-cat-3/item-19.html
/cat1-name/sub-cat-3/item-20.html
/cat1-name/sub-cat-3/item-21.html
/cat1-name/sub-cat-3/item-22.html
/cat1-name/sub-cat-4/item-1.html
/cat1-name/sub-cat-4/item-2.html
/cat1-name/sub-cat-4/item-3.html
/cat1-name/sub-cat-4/item-4.html
/cat1-name/sub-cat-4/item-5.html
/cat1-name/sub-cat-4/item-6.html
/cat1-name/sub-cat-4/item-7.html
/cat1-name/sub-cat-4/item-8.html
/cat1-name/sub-cat-4/item-9.html
/cat1-name/sub-cat-4/item-10.html
/cat1-name/sub-cat-4/item-11.html
/cat1-name/sub-cat-4/item-12.html
/cat1-name/sub-cat-4/item-13.html
/cat1-name/sub-cat-4/item-14.html
/cat1-name/sub-cat-4/item-15.html
/cat1-name/sub-cat-4/item-16.html
/cat1-name/image-1.html
/cat1-name/image-2.html
/cat2-name/item-1.html
/cat2-name/item-2.html
/cat2-name/item-3.html
/cat2-name/item-4.html
/cat2-name/item-5.html
/cat2-name/item-6.html
/cat2-name/item-7.html
/cat2-name/item-8.html
/cat2-name/item-9.html
/cat2-name/item-10.html
/cat2-name/item-11.html
/cat2-name/item-12.html
/cat2-name/item-13.html
/cat2-name/item-14.html
/cat2-name/item-15.html
/cat2-name/item-16.html
/cat2-name/image-1.html
/cat2-name/image-2.html'''.split('\n')

items = []
for it in s:
    _, cat, *rest = it.split('/')
    subcat = ''.join(rest[-2:-1])
    item = rest[-1]
    items.append((cat, subcat, item))

df = pd.DataFrame(items, columns=['category','subcategory','item'])
df.head()
```

Получается такой датафрейм:

```
    category    subcategory item
0   cat1-name   sub-cat-1   item-1.html
1   cat1-name   sub-cat-1   item-2.html
2   cat1-name   sub-cat-1   item-3.html
3   cat1-name   sub-cat-1   item-4.html
4   cat1-name   sub-cat-1   item-5.html
...
```

Дальше всё просто:

```
print('общее количество item в категории:\n',
      df[df['item'].str.contains('item')].groupby('category').size())
print('------')
print('количество item в каждой подкатегории:\n',
      df[df['item'].str.contains('item')].groupby(['category','subcategory']).size())
print('------')
print('количество image в каждой категории:\n',
      df[df['item'].str.contains('image')].groupby('category').size())
```

Вывод:

```
общее количество item в категории:
 category
cat1-name    75
cat2-name    16
dtype: int64
------
количество item в каждой подкатегории:
 category   subcategory
cat1-name  sub-cat-1      25
           sub-cat-2      12
           sub-cat-3      22
           sub-cat-4      16
cat2-name                 16
dtype: int64
------
количество image в каждой категории:
 category
cat1-name    2
cat2-name    2
dtype: int64
```

Вывод если нужно можно сделать по-другому, главное, что всё работает и всё довольно просто выбирать и аггрегировать.

Comment: спасибо! хорошее решение

Answer (score 0):

что-то такое нужно получается?
Я только отдельно image не обрабатывал

```
paths = ['/category-name/sub-cat-name/item-name',
'/category-name/sub-cat-name/item-name-1',
'/category-name/sub-cat-name-1/item-name',
'/category-name/sub-cat-name-1/item-name-1',
'/category-name/image',
'/category-name/image-1',
'/category-name-1/sub-cat-name/item-name',
'/category-name-1/sub-cat-name-1/item-name-1',
'/category-name-2/item',
'/category-name-2/item-1'
         ]


# собрать информацию в дерево
items = dict()

for path in paths:
    components = path[1:].split('/')

    if components[0] not in items:
        items[components[0]] = dict()

    if len(components) > 2:
        if components[1] not in items[components[0]]:
            items[components[0]][components[1]] = dict()

        items[components[0]][components[1]][components[2]] = items[components[0]][components[1]].get(components[2], 0) + 1
    else:
        if '' not in items[components[0]]:
            items[components[0]]['--root--'] = dict()

        items[components[0]]['--root--'][components[1]] = items[components[0]]['--root--'].get(components[1], 0) + 1


# подчитать кол-во items по категориям
for category in items:
    count = 0

    for subcategory in items[category]:
        for item in items[category][subcategory]:
            count += items[category][subcategory][item]

    print(category, count)

print("---")

# подсчитать кол-во items по подкатегориям:
counts = dict()

for category in items:
    for subcategory in items[category]:
        for item in items[category][subcategory]:
            counts[subcategory] = counts.get(subcategory, 0) + items[category][subcategory][item]

for subcategory in counts:
    print(subcategory, counts[subcategory])
```

Comment: спасибо, для категорий с подкатегориями работает хорошо, но почему-то некорректно считает, если все item в корне, по ключу ['cat-2']['--root--'] выводит только последний элемент категории. можете подсказать, как исправить?

Comment: не понял - выложите если возможно тестовые данные (например в своем же вопросе изначальном) чтобы проверить

Comment: дополнил в теле вопроса. print(items['cat2-name']) выводит {'--root--': {'image-2.html': 1}}, а print(items['cat1-name']['--root--']) выводит {'image-2.html': 1}.

Comment: Еще, может быть важно. Подкатегории все подкатегории имеют одинаковые имена. То есть, если есть категории "pants", "shoes", то в обоих случаях подкатегории называются "female", "male"